# Number of group limitation in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there any limitation on number of group that a kafka should have ? Let say a user add comment for a post. So for each post I wanted to create a group so that whenever a new comment come i could notify other user who commented on that post.

Or one solution that is coming in my mind is to subscribe to a partition within a topic `post`

`post/<post id>/<user id>`

Comment: When you are talking about "groups" do you mean consumer groups or do you mean topics? Based on the problem you describe, I would suggest to have a topic with posts and a consumer(-group) which consumes all messages (posts) from the topics and send notification to other users.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you are talking about consumer groups, there is no explicit limit on how many consumer groups you can have. The consumer offsets are saved in zookeeper or in kafka itself based on the version you are using. So, you are only limited by the limitations of zookeeper and operating system you are using.

Comment: You can find some benchmarks [here](https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines)

Answer (score 1):

As [of Kafka 2.2](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-389%3A+Introduce+a+configurable+consumer+group+size+limit), there is a configurable limit on the number of consumers you can have in a consumer group. You can configure it with `group.max.size`

Comment: Isn't that deals with the number of consumers in a consumer group and not the number of consumer groups on a topic.

Comment: Right - it's the max number of consumers you can have in any single consumer group

Comment: good to know there's a configuration we could do at the Kafka broker level. So, if a topic has N partitions and if our application server cluster consists of 2N nodes (or consumers), will Kafka simply reject the additional N consumers from being part of the consumer group?